# Usage of Zsigmondy's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Find the solutions for the equation $$3^x-5^y=z^2$$ where $x,y,z$ are positive integers.

We find one solution $(x,y,z)=(2,1,2)$ by checking small cases. Initially looking at this modulo $4$ one gets that $$(-1)^x-1^y \equiv 0,1 \pmod 4$$ as squares leave residues $0$ and $1$ modulo $4$. This in turn implies that $x$ must be even that is $x=2k$ for integer $k$.

We then have that $$\begin{align}3^{2k}-z^2&=5^y \\ (3^k-z)(3^k+z) &= 5^y \end{align}$$ thus $$\begin{align} 3^k-z &= 5^a \\ 3^k+z &= 5^b \end{align}$$ for such that $b>a\ge1$ and $a+b=y$.

Addin these two equations we eliminate $z$ and get that $$2\cdot 3^k=5^a+5^b =5^a(5^{b-a}+1)$$ the lhs is a multiple of $2$ and the rhs is a multiple of $5$ this makes $5^a=1$ and $a=0$.

Now apparently this is the place where I could apply Zsigmondy's theorem, but I don't know how. Could someone englighten me how to use this theorem? It states that

> Let $a>b\geq1$ be coprime integers, and let $n\geq 2$. Then there exists a prime divisor of $a^n-b^n$ that does not divide $a^k-b^k$ for all $1\leq k< n$, except when: $n=2$, and $a+b$ is a power of $2$; or $(a,b,n)=(2,1,6).$

but I don't see how to put the pieces together.

**Edit:** I think that since $$2\cdot 3^k=5^a+5^b =5^a(5^{b-a}+1)$$ and the fact that $a$ must be $0$ we get the result $b=y$ from $a+b=y$ and so $$2 \cdot 3^k = 5^y +1$$ now due to $\gcd(5,1) =1$ and $5>1$ we can use Zsigmondy's for $y \ge 2$ and we have the existence of prime $p$ for which $p \mid 5^y +1^y$, but $p \nmid 5+1$ i.e $p \nmid 6$. I still don't see how this implies the result?

Comment: Who says Zsigmondy is helpful here???

Comment: about your edit **existence of prime $p$ for which $p \mid 5^y +1^y$, but $p \nmid 5+1$ i.e $p \nmid 6$**  the next observation is that  $p \nmid 6$  means $p \neq 2,3.$   Thus, for that $y,$   we have $p | 2 \cdot 3^k$  which is impossible, contradicting $1 + 5^y = 2 \cdot 3^k$

Comment: see page 2 https://www.math.hkust.edu.hk/excalibur/v16_n4.pdf   I see, they switch   the roles of 3,5

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 forms of Zsigmondy's theorem, one for forms $a^n-b^n$ and one for forms $a^n+b^n$. Your RHS is in the second form.

Comment: I suspect it should be pretty similar?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).